# JSON values not displaying when outputting multiple values (array) to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am iterating over a JSON object via fetch().

I would like to access one of the objects within the objects and iterated over it accessing the key: value pairs and output the values to HTML via list items.

When I try to output the values I only get the last value of the powerstats (there are 6)

What do I need to change here to have all values display properly on my page?

I tried to create a for loop and iterate over the value.length, however value.length gives me 2 as an answer.

Feel free to use the provided api key.

```
 function get_hero(rand_number) {
    const api_key = '10156555926000957';
    let hero_id = rand_number;
    let hero_url = `https://www.superheroapi.com/api/${api_key}/${hero_id}`;

    fetch(hero_url)
    .then(res => { 
      return res.json();
    })
    .then( data => {

      let ps = data.powerstats;

      Object.entries(ps).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        console.log(key + ' - ' + value) // key - value

        console.log(value.length)

        const smt = `<ul>
                      <li>${value}</li>
                      <li>${value}</li>
                      <li>${value}</li>
                      <li>${value}</li>
                      <li>${value}</li>
                      <li>${value}</li>
                    </ul>`;
        const power_stats = document.getElementById('powerstats');
        power_stats.innerHTML = smt;
      })

    })
    .catch(function() {
      console.log('error')
    })
  }
```

[image: browser output and console output]

Comment: You overwrite (not append to) the content of power_stats on each iteration

Comment: How would I append in this case? I created multiple list items, how would I iterated over the keys / values and then add them to the lis??

Comment: One way is `power_stats.innerHTML += smt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sry didn't had coffee yet, XD

so your problem is that you replace all of the `power_stats.innerHTML = smt;` with smt over and over again. You want to use element.appendChild(element) to ADD to a list. Not overwrite

```
.then(data => {

        const ps = data.powerstats;
        const power_stats = document.getElementById('powerstats');
        const list = document.createElement(`ul`)
        power_stats.appendChild(list)


        Object.entries(ps).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            console.log(key + ' - ' + value) // key - value

            console.log(value.length)

            const smt = document.createElement(`li`)
            smt.innerText = `The heroes ${key} is ${value}`
            list.appendChild(smt)
        })

    })
```

Comment: I actually would like to get all the powerstats. This gives me the same result as my code.and your answer only gives me back one powerstat in HTML. What if I want all 6. I will edit my code and you will see what I mean.

Comment: oh btw what A Ralkov is saying about promises is definitively worth while looking into

Comment: Could you explain, I am not sure what is meant by this. I mean, does this have something to due with that I am returning my res.json ? So I am kinda forcing it instead of waiting for some promise to fulfill ? Because if I don't return my res.json the whole thing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you function return void, so you don't wait for `fetch`, so you should return promise:

```
function get_hero(rand_number) {
    const api_key = '10156555926000957';
    let hero_id = rand_number;
    let hero_url = `https://www.superheroapi.com/api/${api_key}/${hero_id}`;

    return fetch(hero_url)
    .then(res => { 
      return res.json();
    })
    .then( data => {

      let ps = data.powerstats;

      Object.entries(ps).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        console.log(key + ' - ' + value) // key - value

        console.log(value.length)

        const smt = `<ul>
                      <li>${value}</li>
                    </ul>`;
        const power_stats = document.getElementById('powerstats');
        power_stats.innerHTML = smt;
      })

    })
    .catch(function() {
      console.log('error')
    })
  }
```

Using:

```
get_hero(123).then(() => console.log('done!'));
```

(for me https://www.superheroapi.com/ is not responding, so maybe it is not the only problem)

Comment: It's working alright, sometimes the characters return null.